# Using HttpContext.RewritePath() with static files

Tags: asp.net, gzip, rewritepath

We use HttpContext.RewritePath() to rewrite the path to static files. We do this to be able to virtualize the location of the static files on the server.

When we do so, IIS seems to behave strangely by sometimes not compressing the content of the file, but by still putting gzip encoding in the http response header. When this happens, browsers fail to properly parse the static file since they try to uncompress cleartext data.

We have been looking around and found a few threads talking about this, but we could not find a satisfying answer as to how to avoid this problem, or why should rewriting paths of static files not be allowed.

Shouldn't it be possible to rewrite the path of a static file?

Here a few pages I found about the issue:

[GZip compression in IIS7 not working, but content-encoding header is set to gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904826/gzip-compression-in-iis7-not-working-but-content-encoding-header-is-set-to-gzip/13075048#13075048)

[HttpContext.RewritePath breakes buildin IIS gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801926/httpcontext-rewritepath-breakes-buildin-iis-gzip)